# Ordering columns in 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, c99

I have a 2D array where the top row is a row of letters (the alphabet) and the bottom row is the frequency that the letter above it occurs in a string. The idea is to place the letters in order of frequency along the top row.

At the moment:

input:

quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog

output:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

11112111111111411211211111

Desired output:

oeruabcdfghijklmnpqstvwxyz

42221111111111111111111111

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

main()
{
    char string[100];
    char s[26][2];
    int c = 0, count[26] = {0};

    printf("Enter a string\n");
    gets(string);

    while ( string[c] != '\0' )
    {
        if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ) 
        count[string[c]-'a']++;

        c++;
    }


    for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
    {
        if( count[c] != 0 )
        {
            s[c][1]=c+'a';
            s[c][2]= (char)(((int)'0')+count[c]);
            gotoxy(c,1);
            printf("%c",s[c][1]);
            gotoxy(c,2);
            printf("%c",s[c][2]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You looked around for an elegant solution , so you don't want to sort the count arr ?

Answer (score 1):

You should find the maximum every iteraton. You can use some fast sort algorithm, but a simple solution is:

```
for (c=0;c<26;c++) {
 int max=-1,letter,i;
 for (i=0;i<26;i++)
  if (count[i]>max) {
   max=count[i];
   letter=i;
  }
 count[letter]=-1;
 gotoxy(c,1);
 s[c][0]='a'+letter;
 printf("%c",s[c][0]);
 gotoxy(c,2);
 s[c][1]='0'+max;
 printf("%c",s[c][1]);
}
```

(Of course, assuming that max<10)

Comment: So you can print it as a digit.

Comment: OK. then you should save in the array the value of `max`. not `'0'+max`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach: take each count, shift it left by five, and bitwise-or the number of the letter in the lower five bits. Sort the resulting numbers, and convert their least-significant five bits back to the letter by and-ing with `0x1F` and adding `'a'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
    int ia = *(int*)a;
    int ib = *(int*)b;
    return (ia>>5) == (ib>>5) ? ia-ib : ib-ia;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char string[100] = "quickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog";
    int c = 0, count[26];
    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));
    while ( string[c] != '\0' ) {
        if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ) {
            count[string[c]-'a']++;
        }
        c++;
    }
            // Shift the letter ordinal into the lower five bits of the count*32
    for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ ) {
        count[c] = (count[c] << 5) | c;
    }
            // Sort the results using the custom compare function
    qsort(count, 26, sizeof(int), compare);
            // Print the letters by taking the lower five bits
    for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ ) {
        printf("%c", 'a'+(count[c]&0x1F));
    }
    printf("\n");
            // Print the counts by ignoring the lower five bits
    for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ ) {
        printf("%d", count[c] >> 5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. Arrays in C are zero-origin, which is to say that your indexes should be `s[c][0]` and `s[c][1]` - your code isn't crashing b/c you're lucky.
2. Typically, the array would be ordered the other way around: `c[2][26]`

As to the sorting … since we're only working with 26 elements and not 2.6 million, how and when you do it is of little consequence.  You can get away with doing a bubble sort.  You could get fancy and build some sort of doubly-linked list and sort it as you go, shuffling elements around.  Have fun with it!

Comment: Thanks very much - will look into bubble sorting